# Caption numbering in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

The page numbering format can be different for each sections of a Word document.

For example: section 1 will have roman numbers (I, ii) and section 2 will have numbers that have "Include chapter number" (1-1, 2-3).

I cannot change the caption format the same way.

What I need is that each section will have a different "Numbering" > "Include chapter number" > "Chapter start with style" type.

For example:

I have a Word file that has a Main part that includes Headings 1-4. Figure captions are then Figure 1-1, Figure 1-3, Figure 3-2.

The second part of the file includes appendices, for which I want the figure captions to be Figure A-1, Figure A-3, Figure C-2.

Is there a way to do this without manually changing something? This is a large manual that is updated with different figures being added to both the main and appendix sections.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You can base the caption numbers on the respective chapter numbers (by inserting chapters as the first part of the number):

[image]

and then:

[image]

This will place the chapter number in front of the caption number

**2.** You can use another type of Captions for each section:

[image]

[image]

They still can all go into one table, as the table can be built by format style.

Comment: Thank you.
Can you please give some practical details on how to implement your two suggestions?
I could not find a way to cross reference within the caption number. How else can I insert a caption other that :Insert>Caption for figures? 
Thanks.

Comment: Have tried the suggestion and played with it a bit.
Option 1: Does not work, because the Heading 1 of the main chapters are numbers (Chapter 1, Chapter 2, etc.), while the Appendices Heading 1 are Appendix A, Appendix B, etc.; therefore, quire a different Heading 1 style.
It would have worked if section break would work on captions as it does for page numbering.
For Option 2: One small issue is having a Label named "Figure" (caption will be be Figure 1-1) and Figure2 causing the caption to be "Figure A-1.

Additional suggestions and solutions will be much welcomed...

Answer (score 0):

Posted the question also in the Microsoft community, and received the following very helpful reply:

Since captions can only be restarted following one of the built-in styles, you will have to use (say) Heading 7 for appendix titles. Create a separate caption label for use with that heading. For details, see http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numberingappendixes.html.